# Retrofit get JsonArray with GSON as default parser

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

this result is send by web service and i try to parse it by simple class which that is like with result structure,

```
{
    "result":
    [
        {
            "id": "386434",
            "weight": "72.000",
            "type": "xxxxx",
            "shamsi_date": "1395/8/5",
            "date": "2016-10-26 10:52:47"
        },
        {
            "id": "395118",
            "weight": "70.000",
            "type": "xxxx",
            "shamsi_date": "1395/8/19",
            "date": "2016-11-09 10:58:29"
        }
    ],
    "message": ""
}
```

as you can see `result` is JsonArray and i would like to get it and put to `JSONARRAY`, and after that i'm trying get `JSONObject`s from that.

## UPDATED CODE:

```
private void getUserAllVisits(String userId) {
    UserAllVisits userAllVisits = new UserAllVisits();
    userAllVisits.setUserId(userId);

    Call<UserAllVisits> call = myService.getUserAllVisitsCall(userAllVisits);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserAllVisits>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserAllVisits> call, final Response<UserAllVisits> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(response.body().getResult()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserAllVisits> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Err: ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

in my code `response.body().getResult().length;` return `2` and i can get `result` array with `response.body().getResult();` but i can't define simple variable as `JSONArray` and assign that to variable as:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().getResult());
```

Comment: Can you please paste UserAllVisits.java?

Comment: If result is an array inside the UserAllVisits.java, you can try something like this JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(response.body().getResult()));

Comment: @AnoopSS I get this error: `Error:(128, 66) error: length in Array is defined in an inaccessible class or interface`

Comment: have you tried the method I suggested?

Comment: yes . this error is for your code as `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(response.body().getResult()));` my post updated

Comment: make this class UserAllVisitsResult public and try

Comment: @AnoopSS ok, now i get this mesage after that, `jsonArray` value is `All elements are null`

Comment: Please update the code with changes you made

Comment: @AnoopSS post updated sir

Comment: @KNeerajLal he doesn't have to use HttpUrlConnection just to get response as string. It can be done with Retrofit itself

Comment: @KNeerajLal My point is that he already have a working network layer in place. Why change that just because you want the result in other way

Comment: @AnoopSS I didn't say he has to change it. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ResponseBody instead of your Pojo class.Try this:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call =    behandamService.getUserAllVisitsCall(userAllVisits);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            //handle Exceptions here
            String jsonString = response.body().string();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Err: ", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

and your interface should be like this

```
@POST // or GET method as per your requirement
Call<ResponseBody> getUserAllVisitsCall(@Body UserAllVisits userAllVisits);
```

Comment: my interface as `UserAllVisits` class which pasted on my post is : `@POST("visits") Call<UserAllVisits> getUserAllVisitsCall(@Body UserAllVisits userAllVisits);` and i get error `Error:(130, 56) error: cannot find symbol method string()` for this line of your code `response.body().string();`

Comment: import okhttp3.ResponseBody; from okhttp3

Comment: my post updated with Retrofit server provider, please review that

Comment: imports of your interface where you have saomthing like this

Comment: Call<ResponseBody> getUserAllVisitsCall();

Comment: `import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
`

Comment: whers is import okhttp3.ResponseBody

Comment: pase your interface method

Comment: for `Call<ResponseBody> getUserAllVisitsCall();` i must be sent some parameters such as `userId`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127945/discussion-between-tux-world-and-android-jack).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the raw string that `Retrofit` returns then you didnt have to use `Retrofit`. The point behind `Retrofit` is to parse the `JSON` using GSON converter. If you don't want that you could have gone with simple `HttpUrlConnection`.

That being said the answer to your question. You can get the raw string from `onResponse` with `response.body().string()`.

**Method 1**

```
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(response.raw().body().string());
JSONArray resultArray = jsonData.getJSONArray("result");
```

**Method 2**

If you GSON library already in the project,

```
JSONArray resultArray = (JSONArray) new Gson().toJson(response.body().getResult());
```

Comment: i get cast error for your code as `JSONArray resultArray = new Gson().toJson(response.body().getResult());`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Pojo class for Response for creating r?
`onResponse(){
 UserAllVisits userAllVisits=response.body();
ResultClass result=userAllVisits.getResult();

}`